# mpls load balancing in the core

Tags: mpls

Hi I am working with this topology:
[image]

The BNG router receives from the 2 NCS5508 (P routers) l2vpn traffic that terminates in l3 on a PWHE interface. Those interfaces are used as subscriber interfaces to establish PPPoE sessions.

the BNG router has an iBGP session with the BG router whom originates a default route for the BNG. So once a PPPoE session is up and running, traffic is sent over the two NCS 5508 routers to the BG.

The BNG router has 2 10x8 bundles towards 5508 #1 and #2
5508 #1 has 2x 40gb links to the BG.
5508#2 has 1x 40gb link to the BG.

**The issue:**

On the NCS 1 router, traffic originating from BNG to the BG will only utilize the .86/.87 link to reach the BG. This doesn't apply in the opposite direction. Traffic from the BG destined to the BNG will actively utilize both links between BG and NCS#1.

Looking at NCS#1 routing table, he correctly knows the destination from both of the links:

```
Routing entry for 172.16.0.161/32
  Known via "ospf 1", distance 110, metric 26, type intra area
  Installed Jan 11 01:09:18.068 for 1d13h
  Routing Descriptor Blocks
    172.16.2.87, from 172.16.0.161, via FortyGigE0/0/0/13
      Route metric is 26
    172.16.2.201, from 172.16.0.161, via FortyGigE0/0/0/14
      Route metric is 26
```

Looking at the CEF:

```
show cef 172.16.0.161 detail               
Fri Jan 12 14:11:58.690 CET
172.16.0.161/32, version 49063, internal 0x1000001 0x30 (ptr 0xa1285d40) [1], 0x0 (0x90919418), 0xa20 (0xa15b6ef8)
 Updated Jan 11 01:09:18.078 
 local adjacency to FortyGigE0/0/0/13

 Prefix Len 32, traffic index 0, precedence n/a, priority 3
  gateway array (0x907692d0) reference count 6, flags 0x68, source lsd (5), 1 backups
                [3 type 5 flags 0x8401 (0x90ec5348) ext 0x0 (0x0)]
  LW-LDI[type=5, refc=3, ptr=0x90919418, sh-ldi=0x90ec5348]
  gateway array update type-time 1 Jan 11 01:09:18.078
 LDI Update time Jan 11 01:09:18.078
 LW-LDI-TS Jan 11 01:09:18.078
   via 172.16.2.87/32, FortyGigE0/0/0/13, 3 dependencies, weight 0, class 0 [flags 0x0]
    path-idx 0 NHID 0x0 [0xa0d7a6a8 0x0]
    next hop 172.16.2.87/32
    local adjacency
     local label 24324      labels imposed {ImplNull}
   via 172.16.2.201/32, FortyGigE0/0/0/14, 6 dependencies, weight 0, class 0 [flags 0x0]
    path-idx 1 NHID 0x0 [0xa0d7bc08 0x0]
    next hop 172.16.2.201/32
    local adjacency
     local label 24324      >>>labels imposed {None}<<<

    Load distribution: 0 (refcount 3)

    Hash  OK  Interface                 Address
    0     Y   FortyGigE0/0/0/13         172.16.2.86
```

It seems that while the BG router passes to the NCS#1 an implicit null label for the .86/.87 link it doesn't do the same for the .200/.201 link and will utilize only one link for forwarding traffic to the BG.

Is this by design? I tried to lab this but the server I am using for GNS3 cannot handle 3 XR devices. Could anyone share any pointers?

Thank you